# Flipping coin $20$ times

Tags: combinatorics

> Amy flipped a coin $20$ times, and got the sequence THHTTTHTTHHTHTTTTTHH. She noticed that $3$ times a heads followed a heads, $7$ times a tails followed a tails, $4$ times a tails followed a heads, and $5$ times a heads followed a tails. How many such sequences are possible?

Here's the solution given in the back of the book:

> Counting heads and tails based on Amy's observations, we see that
>
> - $8$ times a heads follows something,
> - $7$ times something follows a heads,
> - $11$ times a tails follows something,
> - $12$ times something follows a tails.
>
> This implies that any such sequence must have $8$ heads and $12$ tails, and must start with a T and end with an H.

Okay, I've followed the reasoning up to this point. But this next part I don't get.

> "$3$ times a heads followed a head" means that the $8$ heads must occur in $8 - 3 = 5$ groups. There are $\binom{7}{4} = 35$ ways to split the $8$ heads into $5$ positive groups. Similarly, "$7$ times a tail followed a tail" means that the $12$ tails must occur in $12 - 7 = 5$ groups; there are $\binom{11}{4} = 330$ ways to split the into groups.
>
> Therefore, there are $(35)(330) = 11550$ solutions.

Can anyone explain why it follows that $8$ heads must occur in $8 -3 = 5$ groups? And why $12$ tails must occur in $12 - 7 = 5$ groups?

Comment: The groups of heads are as follows:
$$HH$$
$$HH$$
$$HH$$
$$H$$
$$H$$

Comment: Suppose there are $N$ strings of $H$.  We will count them by counting the first $H$ in each string.  The are $8$ $H$s total.  But $3$ of them are a $H$ following a head so they are not the first in the string.  So the remaing $8-3 = 5$ $H$ are the leading $H$ in a string.  As there are $5$ leading $H$s, there are $5$ strings of $H$s.

Comment: @TheBestMagician  Based only on there are $8$ heads, $3$ times a head follows a head, and $5$ times a tail, the groups could be $H, H, H, H, HHHH$ or $H,H,H,HH,HHH$ or $H, H, HH, HH, HH$.

Comment: ... Frankly I'd say.... "for every group of $H$ there must be a leading $H$ and being a leading $H$ it must follow a $T$ (or be the very first flip-- which we've ruled out can't be the case) and every time a $H$ follows a $T$ it must be a leading $H$ in a group.  As there are exactly $5$ times an $H$ follows a $T$ there must be $5$ groups of $H$s."  In fact, I'm really puzzled why the solution *didn't* argue thus.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Can anyone explain why it follows that $8$ heads must occur in $8−3=5$ groups?

As pointed out in comments, it seems they were counting number of beginnings of groups of $H$. Out of all $H$'s, we are given 3 of $H$s are preceeded by another $H$, so these 3 cannot be a beginning of a group, hence only the remaining $8-3=5$ of $H$s correspond to a group beginning.

However this seems unnecessarily complicated, as we can count number of these groups "directly", without complementing (subtracting) ... Since the whole sequence starts with $T$ (already recognized in the solution), we know all groups of $H$ must start with $TH$, and by problem statement there are exactly $5$ of these...

Or we can also count the number of ends of these groups directly - there are $4$ cases of $HT$, plus there is one case of $H$ at the end of the whole sequence (these are the only two ways the group of $H$ can end), so $4+1=5$ groups in total.

The tails case is similar...